# RijndaelManaged equivalent in openssl

Tags: c#, macos, cryptography, openssl

There is some code written using C# which uses [RijndaelManaged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rijndaelmanaged.aspx) class to encrypt data and

 `Mode = CipherMode.CBC`
I need implement the equivalent code in Mac using OpenSSl. 
What is the equivalent to RijndaelManaged in OpenSSl?

Answer (score 2):

RijndaelManaged is just a .NET implementation of the Rijndael algorithm. Rijndael is the  algorithm that was chosen for AES, but AES doesn't use all of the key lengths that are possible with Rijndael (AES is a subset of Rijndael).

If the keys that your code uses with RijndaelManaged are also valid AES keys you can just use OpenSSL's AES functionality; otherwise I'm not sure ... but I'd advise you to stick to the AES subset of Rijndael because that's what everyone else does and it will help you to achieve interoperability.

Comment: Just an update to help out someone hitting this thread. I am in the middle of a .Net encrypted to OpenSSL based decryption problem. OpenSSL does not support a block size of 256 (for data chunks not key length). So Python, Ruby, etc are all failing to decode. If I am wrong, or things change, I look forward to a notification on my comment here. Until then...back to the hunt.